# Why does SQL Server 2008 error out with 80040e14 on INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, odbc

Here is a part of SQL Server T-SQL statement that fails with 80040e14. We use the SQL Native Client driver

```
INSERT INTO T1(<columns>) VALUES('h÷a}¬÷a}8éU','','Uh÷a}¬÷a}','öa}','eöa}Èa¹`îUñõa}H¢','','¸`','`¬ïUÀðUQ¸`¼ø@')
```

I showed values for the varchar columns. They are varchar(254) and the last 4 are varchar(16). The table has other columns (ints and guids).

The same statement works if inserted into a command line tool. It's not clear why it fails. I'd appreciate if someone could point at the most likely cause.

Comment: Is that the actual data that you're trying to insert?  If not, can you post something more readable?

Comment: Is this because "a command line tool" encodes input differently? For example I can see end-of-line in your example, that might be a part of the problem. Also could you please provide the table definition and clarify which exactly "command line tool" you are using.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - yes, it's the actual data, several fields that get this type of junk due to uninitiazlied memory. The other fields are ints.

Comment: @zespri command line tool was sqlcmd, but I also tried an old ODBCTTEST tool that seemed to parse the SQL properly, but I could not execute the command b/c I did not have the right environment. I check in HEX viewer, there are all kids of ASCII values, but in most cases there are no CRs or LFs (0D or OA). Though, there can be any values, I see 01, 06 and more, because it's random junk.

Comment: @marc_s This is legacy code that uses SQL Native Client, which is an ODBC driver.

Comment: OK - SQL Native Client to me is the .NET native client (`SqlConnection` etc.) which is a lot easier to use than ODBC....

Comment: it would take me awhile to obfuscate the column names before I can post the full table def. All character fields are varchars with size 255 or 16 (last 4)